# How to share VirtualBox Guest's Internet Connection with Host?

Tags: virtualbox, internet, connection

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows XP SP3 Installed as a Virtual Machine, the only way for me to access the internet is using a WiMax USB Modem which is not available for Linux, I managed to install it on XP and get it to work but I don't know how to share that connection with Ubuntu.I googled it and found so many workarounds and don't know which the best one that suits my need, I'm not an expert.
Could someone shows me an easy way to do that? Thanks!